# An array for set of label tags

Tags: html

I know it is possible to create an array to store the values of a set of text-boxes.

```
<input name='ArrFirstRowHeading[]' value='A'></input>
<input name='ArrFirstRowHeading[]' value='B'></input>
```

But is it possible to create an array like this for a set of  tags

```
<label name='ArrFirstRowHeading[]'  style='background-color:#D0A9F5;'>A</label>;
<label name='ArrFirstRowHeading[]'  style='background-color:#D0A9F5;'>B</label>;
<label name='ArrFirstRowHeading[]'  style='background-color:#D0A9F5;'>C</label>;
```

The case is I'm getting these values A,B,C in labels from a form. As it is entered it should be shown in a PHP file. Thats only to see the format of the form. Later Im sending these values again to another PHP file to store them in a database. So Instead of showing those A,B,C values in textboxes I need to show them as labels. But I need to send them back to the database. That's why I need them to name

Comment: What's the point? Labels are just labels. They don't get sent as form data. (Also why do you have closing `</input>` tags and semicolons?)

Comment: Why are you storing values in labels?

Comment: Coz in my real question I'm creating a dynamic table. The headings are storing in labels. Then if the displaying format should be able to be displayed. If the format is oki then I need to send them to the database. Instead displaying them in texet boxes I needed to show the table headings in labels. Btw I got the way how to do it. Thanks for trying to help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use hidden field

```
 <label   style='background-color:#D0A9F5;'>A <input type="hidden" name='ArrFirstRowHeading[]' value='A'></label>;
 <label   style='background-color:#D0A9F5;'><input type="hidden" name='ArrFirstRowHeading[]' value='B'>B</label>;
 <label   style='background-color:#D0A9F5;'>C <input type="hidden" name='ArrFirstRowHeading[]' value='C'></label>;
```